# Are there typically rate limits to querying DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

Are there typically rate limits to querying DNS?  If I want to ask 8.8.8.8 for about 30k queries, how slowly must I make the requests so as not to cause or get in trouble?

I've searched for rate limits on dns queries but I'm not finding any relevant results.

Comment: 1. Why wouldn't you ask the entity that manages 8.8.8.8? 2. What kind of `trouble` are you imagining?

Comment: sorry, 8.8.8.8 is google's public DNS.  And the "trouble" would be either causing a DoS (unlikely) or at least appearing to be attempting a DoS (even though I'm not, the purpose is legit).

Comment: And I've reviewed google's FAQs and I don't see hard numbers.  But that doesn't mean they would take kindly to it.  I'm just checking.

Comment: How many queries per second do you think 8.8.8.8 handles?  Do you really think you can DoS google?

Comment: No I don't think I can DoS google.  I said that.  But I just don't know what the limit is before I end up on some blacklist.

Comment: @toppledwagon - roughly about 800,000/sec.  But they do limit QPS per IP.

Comment: @jason could you use a proxy ? Something like DotProxy to query on different dns concurrently. I'm also looking at this

Comment: In theory you could use WHOIS or RDAP to determine the authoritative nameserver for each domain, and only fall-back to a non-authoritative NS like 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google does do `response rate limiting` on their DNS servers.

You can see their full info here: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/security#rate_limit

> Google Public DNS implements two kinds of rate control:
>
> - Rate control of outgoing requests to other nameservers. To protect other DNS nameservers against DoS attacks that could be launched from
>     our resolver servers, Google Public DNS enforces per-nameserver QPS
>     limits on outgoing requests from each serving cluster.
> - Rate control of outgoing responses to clients. To protect any other systems against amplification and traditional distributed DoS (botnet)
>     attacks that could be launched from our resolver servers, Google
>     Public DNS performs two types of rate limiting on client queries: To
>     protect against traditional volume-based attacks, each server
>     imposes per-client-IP QPS and average bandwidth limits.
>         To guard against amplification attacks, in which large responses to small queries are exploited, each server enforces a
>     per-client-IP maximum average amplification factor. The average
>     amplification factor is a configurable ratio of response-to-query
>     size, determined from historical traffic patterns observed in our
>     server logs.
>
>   If queries from a specific source IP address exceed the maximum QPS, or exceed the average bandwidth or amplification limit
>     consistently (the occasional large response will pass), we return
>     (small) error responses or no response at all.

Comment: But what might that limit be?  How slow should I have to go to avoid getting errors?

Comment: They aren't going to publicly disclose this I would think, but an online query shows one post stating it is around 500 QPS per IP.